# How to add bamboo build log lines into bamboo notification template?

Tags: java, freemarker, bamboo

I am currently getting bamboo notification emails, but it doesn't have any log lines included in it, I wanted to include last 100 lines of bamboo logs into notification email once bamboo plan is completed.

I was going through [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/modifying-notification-templates-289276982.html) documentation to customize bamboo notification templates but I couldn't find how to fetch log lines into my freemarker template. Please help me with this, I'm new to both freemarker & bamboo.